# Got any more of them pixels? Is this sentence grammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

> Got any more of them pixels? (from a meme)

and

> Now hand me them scissors.

I don't remember the sources, but I find this pattern of sentence used in movies and blogs. Being a non-native speaker, I can't tell if it is grammatically correct or just used for comic effect.

I'm asking because I think `them + noun` carries a slightly different nuance than `those + noun`. And I was hoping to use it in an article I'm writing for the college magazine (which will be read by non-native speakers).

tl;dr How correct is the pattern `... + them + noun + ...` when used instead of `... + those + noun + ...`?

Comment: "..them+noun.." is not correct, so use "those" instead. And what do you mean by "pixels"? You better make sure of it since it is _the smallest unit of digital images_, not a physical tool to be handled around.

Comment: @TasneemZh Oh. No, the top two sentences are not related in anyway (I've edited it now). I know what a pixel means. You sure it's not correct? because I have seen it used in many places (mostly in speech but ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *them* in place of *those* as a demonstrative determiner is a feature of some non-standard English dialects.

As with most non-standard dialectical English, people often think of constructions like "them pixels" as sounding uneducated and lower class.

For example, in American English, one dialect that include this feature is Smokey Mountain English, spoken in the southern Appalachian region, which has traditionally been very rural and quite poor. A speaker of this dialect might say, "I'm afeared of them copperheads" instead of the standard, "I'm afraid of those copperheads" or "them's not perch, them's bass" instead of the standard, "those are not perch, those are bass" (["Grammar and Syntax of Smoky Mountain English (SME)"](http://artsandsciences.sc.edu/appalachianenglish/node/796)).